# Python - is this loop correct?

Tags: python, loops

```
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

def sub(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2

def multi(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2

def div(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2

print("\t\t\tCalculator App")

def main():
    operation = input("\nWhat do you want to do: (+, -, *, /)? ")
    if(operation != "+" and operation != "-" and operation != "*" and operation != "/"):
       #invalid operation
       print("You have entered an invalid key")
    else:
       var1 = int(input("Please number : "))
       var2 = int(input("Please enter another number : "))
       if(operation == "+"):
           print("Answer is: ", add(var1, var2))
       elif(operation == "-"):
           print("Answer is: ", sub(var1, var2))
       elif(operation == "*"):
           print("Answer is: ", multi(var1, var2))
       else:
           print("Answer is: ", div(var1,var2))

main()

rerun = input("ReRun? (y/n)") 
while(rerun == "y"):
    main()
    rerun = input("ReRun? (y/n) ") 
else:
    exit()
```

Reading books, watching videos, and self study has been challenging.

Please let me know if this is the correct way to loop this program, i'm sure there are alternatives.

Comment: Are there any observable errors in your program?

Comment: That program looks a simple way of doing, and if it works without errors then looks good to me

Comment: @logic I think it works but Pycool0 is curious to  the proper method to loop a program like this?

Comment: Shouldn't that question be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Looks pretty good if you're using Python 3. Indentation is a little out though...

Comment: This would be off-topic for Code Review without a bit more context, and also for @Pycool0 to confirm that this code actually works as intended (which intention, curiously, is not stated at all in the question)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the rerun loop down at the bottom, the following is probably cleaner:

```
while True:
    main()
    if input("ReRun? (y/n) ") == 'n':
        break
```

It should be noted that it defaults to rerunning if the user enters something not expected.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done something like

```
operators = dict()  
operators['+'] = lambda x,y: x+y
operators['-'] = lambda x,y: x-y
operators['*'] = lambda x,y: x*y
operators['/'] = lambda x,y: x/y

def main():
    operation = input("\nWhat do you want to do: (+, -, *, /)? ")

    if operation in operators:
        var1 = int(input("Please number : "))
        var2 = int(input("Please enter another number : "))
        print("Answer is: ", operators[operation](var1, var2))
    else:
        print("You have entered an invalid key")

while True:
    main()
    if input("ReRun? (y/n) ") == 'n':
        break
```

Which I believe is more readeable and easier to expand (add new operators)

Comment: Hi all, the program executes perfectly, without error. I have studied all sorts of programming langs, still consider my a noob,and seeking for alternative methods. Thanks to those whom provides suggestions.